# how can I set a HD screen recording using getDisplayMedia api?

Tags: webrtc, webapi, screen-recording, get-display-media, videoquality

I have created a screen recorder application using **getDisplayMedia()** API but the output video quality is not good, is there any way to configure the output video quality to get HD resolution video?

I got a similar kind of question ->  https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/-KC3xg4MEp4 but solution is not available

```
var constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: {
    width: { ideal: 720, max: 1920 },
    height: { ideal: 1024, max: 1080 }
  }
}
video_stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(constraints);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer, in order to set the good resolution just update the **constraint**  and the output video quality will be better.

```
var constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: {
    width: { ideal: 1920, max: 1920 },
    height: { ideal: 1080, max: 1080 }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is also helpful. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/1812